# How to run Cloud Dataflow pipelines using Spark runner?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have read that Google Cloud Dataflow pipelines, which are based on Apache Beam SDK, can be run with Spark or Flink.

I have some dataflow pipelines currently running on GCP using default Cloud Dataflow runner and I want to run it using Spark runner but I don't know how to.

Is there any documentation or guide about how to do this? Any pointers will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're using Java but the equivalent process applies with Python.

You need to migrate your pipeline to use the Apache Beam SDK, replacing your Google Dataflow SDK dependency with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add the dependency for the runner you wish to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And add the `--runner=spark` to specify that this runner should be used when submitting the pipeline.

See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/ for the full list of runners and comparison of their capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to multiple tutorials and documentation scattered all over the web, I was finally able to have a coherent idea about how to use spark runner with any Beam SDK based pipeline.

I have documented entire process here for future reference: http://opreview.blogspot.com/2018/07/running-apache-beam-pipeline-using.html.